# TextField Loses Focus with setState

Tags: flutter, keyboard, focus, textfield

I have a custom `StatefulWidget` that when typing into an empty field, it will automatically add a new empty field below so the user can keep adding data.

However, as I use `setState` in `onChanged` to add the new field, the keyboard is dismissed and focus is lost on the currently focused field.

How can Io prevent this happening?

```
 TextField(
          hintText: widget.newEntryHint,
          text: data[index].value,
          onChanged: (val) {
            setState(() {
              data[index].value = val;
    
              //if last item in list, add an extra field below
              if (val.length > 0 && index == (data.length -1)) {
                data.add(TextListItem(value: ""));
              }
            });
          },
        )
```

Custom TextField for reference:

```
class MyTextField extends StatefulWidget {
  MyTextField({
    this.text,
    this.hintText = "",
    this.onChanged,
    this.onSubmitted,
    this.textAlign = TextAlign.left,
    this.focusNode,
    this.autofocus = false,
    this.obscureText = false,
    this.padding = const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    this.keyboardType = TextInputType.text,
    this.canEdit = true,
    this.isDarkMode = false,
    this.textCapitalization = TextCapitalization.sentences,
    this.key,
  });

  final String text;
  final String hintText;
  final ValueChanged<String> onChanged;
  final ValueChanged<String> onSubmitted;
  final TextAlign textAlign;
  final FocusNode focusNode;
  final bool autofocus;
  final bool obscureText;
  final EdgeInsets padding;
  final TextInputType keyboardType;
  final TextCapitalization textCapitalization;
  final Key key;

  final bool canEdit;

  final isDarkMode;

  @override
  _MyTextFieldState createState() => _MyTextFieldState();
}

class _MyTextFieldState extends State<MyTextField> {
  static const double textFieldPadding = 12.0;
  TextEditingController editingController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    editingController = TextEditingController(text: widget.text);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IgnorePointer(
      ignoring: !widget.canEdit,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                top: textFieldPadding + widget.padding.top, bottom: textFieldPadding + widget.padding.bottom, left: widget.padding.left, right: widget.padding.right),
            child: TextField(
              key: widget.key,
              maxLines: null,
              textCapitalization: widget.textCapitalization,
              keyboardType: widget.keyboardType,
              keyboardAppearance: widget.isDarkMode ? Brightness.dark : Brightness.light,
              controller: editingController,
              onSubmitted: widget.onSubmitted,
              onChanged: widget.onChanged,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: widget.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : MyColors.textBlue,
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              autofocus: widget.autofocus,
              focusNode: widget.focusNode,
              textAlign: widget.textAlign,
              obscureText: widget.obscureText,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: widget.hintText,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(
                    color: widget.isDarkMode ? MyColors.black[700] : MyColors.grey,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            color: widget.isDarkMode ? MyColors.black : MyColors.grey[150],
            height: 1.0,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using a custom `TextField` class? because the standard Flutter `TextField` doesn't have a text property.

Comment: Yep, I am using a custom class, but just applies some styling and direct text setting, per `text` property.

Comment: Ok, would be useful to see the source of that class in the question, as I suspect the problem is occurring in your custom class.

Comment: Added it in for reference.

Answer (score 16):

I have had the same problem. I have found that I use `key: UniqueKey()` in my container. On every `setState` it generates `uniqueKey` and updates the children. Check your keys.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've replaced UniqueKey() with ValueKey(0) and now there is no issue with input in TextFormField, though Dissmisable widget now doesn't work as before. What did you mean with check your keys? How to solve this issue?

Comment: I had the same problem, I was defining a GlobalKey() for my Scaffold inside build function, I just moved it outside the function.

Comment: i have same problem as mentioned by @Jan in above comment with dismissable widget? Have you found solution @Jan?

Comment: shraddha11 no sorry I didn't found solution, instead I've made workaround, removed setState((){}) from onChanged parameter in TextFormField and then don't have this issue

Comment: @Jan @shraddha11 You will have to create a `ValueKey` based on a final id. For instance `key: ValueKey(task.id)` (inside your `Dismissible`).

Comment: I'm using a `TextFormField` inside a `Dismissible` widget. Although it solves the keyboard issue, now I'm facing an issue with the text cursor position. I'm using a setState on each text change, and each time the pointer jumps to the beginning of the text. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

In my case , that issue was about the key of TextFormField.

I created a formkey at outside of the page

```
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
```

and than I gave that key to textformfield as a parameter

```
 TextFormField(
              focusNode: textFormFieldFocusNode,
              key: _formKey,
              ....
              ....
```

I hope it creates a perspective to that kind problems.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, maybe something was fixed since then, but I'm not seeing your issue anymore. At least with the way I'm setting up your widget (*slight difference between your `data.add()` vs my `fields.add()`*).

```
List<Widget> _fields;
ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();

_buildData() {
  _fields = new List();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    _fields.add(_createMyTextField('hello$i', i));
  }
}

Widget _createMyTextField(String text, int index) {
  return MyTextField(
    text: text,
    hintText: 'hello hint$index',
    onChanged: (val) {
      setState(() {
        //if last item in list, add an extra field below
        if (val.length > 0 && index == (_fields.length-1)) {
          _fields.add(_createMyTextField("", index+1));
        }
      });
    },
  );
}

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _buildData();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title)),
    body: ListView(
      controller: controller,
      children: _fields.toList()
    )
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Could you explain how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue. The problem in my case was caused by a `Container` in the tree having an optional `margin` that was controlled by the focus within the child tree. When a `TextFormField` was tapped the keyboard would pop up and down and the field did not have focus. However, the container's margin was correctly changed due to the focus.

By changing the container to have a margin of 0 instead of null, it fixed the problem. It may also apply to other properties like padding etc.